# Python Behave raise test failure on except

Tags: python, cucumber, python-behave

I am writing a cucumber type test using behave in Python.  When an API fails I want the test to fail, what should I do to that, please?

```
def check_api(self, text, api_format):
    request_url = f'{self._base_url}{api_format}?text={text}'

    try:
        request_response = requests.get(url = request_url)

    except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError:
        print('what goes here please?')
```

Thank you

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how to fail the step explicitly in behave step implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46274276/how-to-fail-the-step-explicitly-in-behave-step-implementation)

Comment: @DamiãoMartins Thank you that does if you want to make it an answer I will mark it as accepted.  I struggled to find the syntax when I looked.